# Genero de un nombre

Tags: javascript

Necesito definir el genero de un nombre, lo quiero hacer de la manera que todos los que terminen con una 'a' sean de mujeres, de lo contrario sean de hombre.

El nombre del cual desee averiguar el genero va a ser ingresado por un input, quiero saber como hago que en JavaScript me lea la ultima letra del nombre ingresado por el input.

No se en que parte me estoy equivocando ya que no lo he logrado.

Este es mi html:

````
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Averigua el genero de un nombre</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container text-center py-5">
        <h1>Averigua el genero de un nombre</h1>
        <div class="py-4">  
          <input type="text" id="nombre" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="ej: Laura">
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="boton" name="btn-validar" value="validar" 
         onclick="detectarGenero()">
        <div id="resultado" class="py-4"></div>
    </div>    
    <script src="Names2.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>```

Este es mi JS:

```function detectarGenero(){
    
    var nombre_ingresado = (document.getElementById('nombre'));
    var letra = (nombre_ingresado-1);
    
    console.log(letra);

    if(letra == 'a'){
        document.write('Es mujer');
    }
    else{
        document.write('Es Hombre');
    }
}```
````

Comment: ¿Cuál es la intención de esta línea `var letra = (nombre_ingresado-1);`? Si quisieras la última letra deberías hacer algo coo `let letra = nombre_ingresado[nombre_ingresado.length - 1]`

Comment: Muchas gracias Jacobo ya lo corregí, sin embargo, cuando voy a probar el codigo en consola me aparece "undefined".

Comment: Es porque no estás obteniendo el valor del nombre. Obtienes el elemento pero no su valor. Debes cambiar esto `document.getElementById('nombre')` por esto `document.getElementById('nombre').value`.

Comment: Mil gracias Jacobo! ya me funciono :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos errores en tu código.

El primero es que no estás obteniendo el valor del elemento con `id` igual a `nombre`. El segundo es que no estás obteniendo el valor de la última letra del nombre.

Tu código debería quedar de la siguiente manera.

```
function detectarGenero() {
    var nombre_ingresado = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var letra = nombre_ingresado[nombre_ingresado.length - 1];
        
    console.log(letra);
    
    if(letra == 'a')
        document.write('Es mujer');
    else
        document.write('Es Hombre');
}
```